# To get only the regular files and directories but not the hidden files and directories

Tags: linux, unix

find -type f | grep -ril 'String' ~

```
/home/ankit/.bash_history
/home/ankit/.filename.swo
/home/ankit/.filename.swp
/home/ankit/.perl_Eg.pl.swp
/home/ankit/.sample.swl
/home/ankit/.sample.swm
/home/ankit/.sample.swn
/home/ankit/.sample.swo
/home/ankit/.sample.swp
/home/ankit/.viminfo
/home/ankit/ankitrai
/home/ankit/array.sh
/home/ankit/array2.sh
/home/ankit/d1/text.txt
/home/ankit/direct/space
/home/ankit/filename
/home/ankit/function1.sh
/home/ankit/mail.pl
/home/ankit/perl_Eg.pl
/home/ankit/test.sh
/home/ankit/tmp
```

i'm using the above command to search a file with the string but it was giving the hidden files also,i dont need the hidden files and directories.

Comment: `find . -type f -name "[^.]*"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can u explain it

Comment: Sure, you are just finding all file using the pattern `[^.]*` which is a `[..list..]` that says match files `'^'` (not) starting with a `'.'`. The *circumflex* at the beginning of the *list* simply says *invert-the-match*, so `[^.]*` says match files that don't begin with a dot `:)` If you only wanted files starting with `'a'` or `'b'` or `'c'`, you could use `[abc]*`. If you only wanted file NOT starting with  `'a'` or `'b'` or `'c'`, you would use `[^abc]*`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks